# Asp.net visual studio just in time debugger error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I write this code to handler client request:

```
  HttpContext content = HttpContext.Current;
  Handler3 handler = new Handler3();
  handler.ProcessRequest(content);
```

but when the client send to my server, my server is crash and show me this error message:
An unhandled Microsoft.Net Framework exception occured in w3wp.exe [1268].
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: what is the actuall exception? Please share that.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan thanks my dear friend,i reinstall the my vs and my problem is solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset your Visual studio,should be done.